# ls -v (natural number sorting) command sorts capitalized files/dirs ahead of non-capitalized files/dirs

Tags: debian, ls

I'd like to have natural sorting of numbers, but *capitalized files/dirs not sorted at the top.* Is that possible?

Currently `ls -lv` produces:

```
FOO/
bar/
ZEBRA.x
foo.x
foo-1.x
foo-2.x
foo-10.x
```

I messed around with `|sort ...` but (1) nothing I tried worked and (2) it removed `--color=auto` from my `ls` command. I'm sure there's a fix for the color, but I have no idea what it is.

**EDIT**

In my testing, `LC_COLLATE=C ls -l` does the same thing as `ls -lv`.

Comment: You can force color with `--color=always` , but you might want to focus your question on the sorting (since `|sort` didn't fix anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting in `ls` depends on your locale settings, however, unfortunately this is not considered when using `ls -v` and `sort -V`.

Check `LC_COLLATE="C" ls -l` and see the same "issue".

> This functionality is implemented using gnulib's filevercmp function, which has some caveats worth noting.
>
> - LC_COLLATE is ignored, which means ‘ls -v’ and ‘sort -V’ will sort non-numeric prefixes as if the LC_COLLATE locale category was set to ‘C’.

[(via)](https://www-zeuthen.desy.de/unix/unixguide/infohtml/coreutils/Details-about-version-sort.html)

It means it will be sorted in ASCII order.

See also:

https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Version-sort-ignores-locale

---

However, you could e.g. use `python` to sort your versions:

Install `natsort` module, e.g. if you have `pip` installed:

```bsh
pip3 install natsort
```

Put the following in a python script (e.g. `sortv.py`):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from natsort import humansorted
import sys
for line in humansorted(sys.stdin):
    print(line.rstrip())
```

Then run `ls -1f | python /path/to/sortv.py`.

This is nowhere perfect, it does not care about directories vs files, it should just show what you can do. Better would be to implement the whole thing in `python` and not pipe from `ls` [which should never be parsed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)!

E.g.:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
from natsort import humansorted
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk('.'):
    for d in dirs:
        print('\033[94m{}\033[0m'.format(d))
    for f in humansorted(f):
        print(f)
    break
```

Comment: I tried `LC_COLLATE=C ls -l`, with and without `-v` and as you said, they do the same thing. So does this answer mean it can't be done without piping through `sort` or something else?

Comment: This answer means it **cannot** be done with `ls` or `sort`.

Comment: I'll give the python script a try in a bit. Thanks for taking the time and if you have anything else to add, it will be more than welcome.

Comment: added a python-only `ls -v`. Need to be extended for more colors and `ls -l` functionality. It also does not take arguments but always uses current dir.

Answer (score 2):

You could always use `zsh`'s `numericglobsort` or `n` glob qualifier instead.

```
$ locale title
English locale for Britain
$ print -rC1 -- *(Nn)
bar
FOO
foo-1.x
foo-2.x
foo-10.x
foo.x
ZEBRA.x
```

```
$ () { local LC_COLLATE=C; print -rC1 -- *(Nn); }
FOO
ZEBRA.x
bar
foo-1.x
foo-2.x
foo-10.x
foo.x
```

With GNU `ls`:

```
ls -U -ld --color -- *(n)
```

For `ls` not to sort (and list files in the order they were given by `zsh`'s glob expansion).

If your locale's sort order is case sensitive like in the C locale, you can also do:

```
$ locale title
ISO/IEC 14652 i18n FDCC-set
$ print -rC1 -- *(Nnoe['REPLY=$REPLY:l'])
bar
FOO
foo-1.x
foo-2.x
foo-10.x
foo.x
ZEBRA.x
```

Were we use the `oe` glob qualifier to rewrite the names to `l`ower case for `o`rdering by `e`valuating the `REPLY=$REPLY:l` `e`xpression.

With GNU `sort`, `-V` (for version sort) can be combined with `-f` (case insensitive matching), but that assumes file names don't contain newline characters, and that only works for ASCII letters:

```
$ ls | LC_COLLATE=C sort -Vf
bar
ETE
FOO
foo.x
foo-1.x
foo-2.x
foo-10.x
ZEBRA.x
Á
ÉTÉ
á
été
```